# spring: change single repository method

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

to make it super simple
I got base entity class with just id field
1st class extends base entity and got additional field string "size"
2nd class extends base entity and got additional field string "color"

I want to make repository with method

```
public interface myRepository<T extends BaseEntity, IdT> extends JpaRepository<T, IdT> {

  Optional<T> findFirstByIdentifier(String identifier);
}
```

where identifier is (depending on the type) size or color

something like calling Optional findFirstByColor(String colorName);
and Optional findFirstBySize(String sizeName);
inside Optional findFirstByIdentifier(String identifier); depending what the T type is
Is there a simple way to do this?

I was thinking about making class with just
Optional findFirstByIdentifier(String identifier);
and instead of declaring it in "myRepository" doing this in another repository class like
myRepositorySearchQuery, then making myRepositorySearchQueryImpl, but then i would need another repository class with Optional findFirstBySize(String sizeName); to call it into the implementation and decided it would be better to just ask for some tip

Comment: Could you explain your use case - why do you want a single repository across these two entities, instead of just going the conventional route of declaring two separate `JpaRepository` interfaces for them?

Comment: I want to create abstract service<T> and call findFirstBy'identifier' method there that will return T object depending on the service type

Comment: @priyank-sriv just a bad way to do simple thing. Anyway thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

This was just a crappy idea.
I just created
abstract method in abstract class for finding object
two repositories for both classes
autowired them in abstract class implementations and used inside the abstract method mentioned above

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).